# how to find min and max in loadash

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
{
  "item_name": "Chicken Tangy Combo",
  "item_key": "mezvts3qv1rl56vj",
  "item_price": 22,
  "quantity": 1,
  "ingredients": [
    {
      "group_key": "9lleke6mc60ulon1",
      "key": "qjuejdqhhcyz0orm",
      "ingredient_name": "2 Bread",
      "price": 1,
      "qun": 1,
      "max": 1,
      "min": 0
    },
    {
      "group_key": "qctfdwlc54v8xdet",
      "key": "rkgqnzkpktjfkfwz",
      "ingredient_name": "Onion Rings",
      "price": 3,
      "qun": 1,
      "max": 2,
      "min": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

how to find max and min by using loadash

i used `_(this.item.ingredients).groupBy('group_key').map((objs, key) => ({ 'group_key': key, 'total': _.sumBy(objs, 'qun'), 'max':_.maxBy(objs, 'max')})).value();`

the groupBy and sumBy working fine but can't able to get the max vale instead i get the whole object

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about Loadash and when searching for it, I found Lodash and selected _.max in the menu..

https://lodash.com/docs#max , https://lodash.com/docs#maxBy

Perhaps this: `_(this.item.ingredients).groupBy('group_key').map((objs, key) => ({ 'group_key': key, 'total': _.sumBy(objs, 'qun'), 'max':_.max(objs, 'max')})).value();`